# what are the steps for adding and apple associated domain file to my website for password autofill?

Tags: swift, associated-domains

What steps do I need to take other than adding the file to my website in the .well-known directory and adding the entitlement in my app?

Does my server need to code sign my apple app entitlement file for password autofill in my iOS app? I saw an old post that said the server needed to sign it but as far as I do not see anything mentioning that in Apple's documentation